# Cable compatibility: will SAS 6GB/s fallback to 3 GB/s?

Tags: hardware-raid, sas

I’m just in the process of configuring a server for RAID 1 by inserting an IBM ServerRAID M1015 card and two Seagate ST2000NM0023 SAS drives. Both controller and drives are rated as 6 GB/s. Unfortunately I could only get a fan-out cable with 3 GB/s rating.

Question: can I use it? Will the controller or the disks realize this and fallback to slower transfer speeds or am I heading for troubles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LSI, which has to say a word about SAS, is [telling us](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/Direct%20Assets/LSI/6Gbs_SAS_Technology_Overview.pdf):

> Key 6 Gb/s SAS features:
>
> [...]
>
> - 6 Gb/s SAS operates over existing passive infrastructure
>
>   - uses the existing backplanes and cables

So no, neither the controller nor the disks would realize that a 3 GB/s SAS cable is used, but as the rating characteristics seem not to have changed, it would operate at 6 GB/s speeds as designed.

Comment: Wonderful, thx!

Comment: Bear in mind that a keyword in this quote is passive.  If you have backplanes using older expanders you will be limited.

Answer (score 1):

It should work at 6Gbps. But you've already purchased everything. Build it up and go from there.